# Can tkinter button click not issue a leave event?

Tags: events, tkinter

I use the tkinter Leave event to tell when the mouse hovers away from a button, which is fine, but clicking the button also issues a Leave event even though the mouse is still hovering over the button.

Can I configure the button to not issue a Leave event when clicking the button?  Alternatively, can the leave event handler check something to know that the mouse is still over the button?

Sample code for showing that clicking the button also undesirably runs its Leave event:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from tkinter import * 

def handle_click(e):
    print("click")

def handle_leave(e):
    print("leave")

root = Tk()

b = Button(root, text="Button")
b.pack()
b.bind('<Button-1>', handle_click)
b.bind('<Leave>', handle_leave)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Which operating system are you using? For me (windows 7) a click does not trigger `leave` event and your code works fine.

Comment: Your code works fine on OSX too -- no `<Leave>` events when clicking.

Comment: I am using Fedora 20 with XFCE 4.10 desktop.  I tried Windows and it works fine for me, too.  Looks like I just need a workaround for my environment.

Comment: My workaround to handle my environment is to disregard the leave event when the event's x,y coordinates lie within the Button.